# Toggle with an IF statement needs two clicks to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a toggle of a ‘follow-unfollow’ button of a Twitter like following system. When the button has the class `unfollow` it takes two clicks to trigger to fire. When the button has the class `follow` it fires in one click. This is related to the `if` statement. If the script does not need to run through the `if` statement it fires well on one click which is the part of the `else` section of the script. It is worth noting, that when two clicks are needed, if there is no refresh in the page, you then can toggle back and forth with just one click as it is supposed to be. Do you know how can I avoid using two clicks when the script needs to go through the `if` statement?

Thanks in advance.

```
<button class="followUnfollow" id="boton<?php echo $member->id; ?>" type="button" data-member_id="<?php echo $member->id; ?>" user_id="<?php echo $id;?>"> <?php echo $status; ?> </button>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#boton<?php echo $member->id; ?>").on('click', function() {
        var memberId = $(this).attr('data-member_id');
        var userId = $(this).attr('user_id');
         if($("#boton<?php echo $member->id; ?>").hasClass('unfollow')) { // TWO CLICKS TO FIRE
             $.get("follow_actions.php", {unfollow_id:memberId, user_id:userId} , function(data) {
             });            
             $(this).html('follow');
             $(this).removeClass('unfollow').addClass('follow');
         } else { // WORKS WELL, ONE CLICK TO FIRE
             $.get("follow_actions.php", {follow_id:memberId, user_id:userId} , function(data) {
             });
             $(this).html('unfollow');
             $(this).removeClass('follow').addClass('unfollow');
         }
    });
   }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `class` rather than `id` ? i think you have lot of follow/unfollow buttons?

Comment: Is the "unfollow" class set from the page load? It could seem that the button doesn't have the class from the start, and the script therefore is adding it on the first click, before it can evalute as `true` in the if-statement

Comment: `$("#boton<?php echo $member->id; ?>").on('click', function() {` make it fire after two clicks. Please use common `class` to do what you want to do

Comment: As Chri.s noted you must set an initial class, "follow" or "unfollow", to the button.

Comment: @Chri.s you are right! That was the problem. I just added the class dinamically with PHP and problem solved. Thank you very much man!

Comment: @Koas right on! That was the problem. Thank you very much.